Method-of-moment of n IID random variables
The method-of-moment of $\sigma$ for the following pdf is
$$
\text{pdf}(x,\sigma) = \frac{x}{\sigma^2}\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2})
$$
$$
E[x] = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2}\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2})dx
$$
$$
E[x] = \sqrt\frac{\pi}{2}\sigma
$$
$$
\sigma^2 = \frac{2}{\pi}E^2[x]
$$
Now how can I calculate the same moment for a pdf of $n$ IID random variables?
$$
\text{pdf}(x,\sigma) = \prod_{1}^{n}\frac{x_i}{\sigma^2}\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x_i^2}{\sigma^2})
$$

In statistical notation, you are asking how to compute expressions like $E[X^kY^j]$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.  But since that implies $X^k$ and $Y^j$ are independent, the expectation factors and you're done.

"$x$" appears to be doing double duty in your question; you might consider adopting a different symbol for the random variable and for the dummy in the density. Conventionally that would be to use $X$ for the random variable in expressions like $E[X]$.
